# Accessing Pendrive in Ubuntu using Wine

Tags: ubuntu, wine

We use ubuntu in our college and they have blocked pendrive access. When we insert pendrive it displays a dialog that says "There is no application to handle this file" (or something like that).

So, as a workaround some one suggested us to use wine in ubuntu to access the pendrive. We already have wine installed on the system, is there any software(windows particularly as it has to be opened using wine) to get this going ?

I'm not sure how far I'm correct with what I'm retrospecting.

And yes, we don't have root access

Comment: Why would you use wine to handle an operating system operation?

Comment: Wait, you don't have root but you could install wine?

Comment: If you get caught trying to work-around IT policy, no matter how stupid it may be, they can come down on you pretty hard. For "unauthorized use of computer systems" you could risk expulsion from school, firing in the workplace, and/or criminal prosecution in either. How lucky do you feel?

Comment: Have you tried to actually _access_ the files? The message you get probably just means that there is no autoplay configured not that you can't access the drive.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your pendrive might have autorun file. Nautilus will show a "There is no application to handle this file" message when autorun file tries to open an unknown type of file.
2. The authority blocked nautilus from opening the pendrive

You may use:
    sudo mount /deb/sdb1 /mnt
    sudo nautilus /mnt

However, fooling your college authority is not good.